# GRUB: "invalid arch independent ELF magic" after install on SSD

Tags: grub2, partitioning, filesystem, ssd

I've got a brand new laptop with a 128GB SSD drive. I read that aligning the partitions to match the Erase Block Size of the SSD is important. I followed William Scott's guide [SSD Tweaks in Linux and Aligning Partitions](http://williamscott.me/blog/2010/12/ssd-tweaks-linux-align-partitions/) and my partitions ended up being:

```
$ sudo fdisk -lu /dev/sda

Disk /dev/sda: 128.0 GB, 128035676100 bytes
32 heads, 32 sectors/track, 244208 cylinders, total 250069680 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00037bd2

   Device Boot       Start        End     Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *         1024     206847     102912   83  Linux
/dev/sda2           206848   16985087    8389120   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3         16985088  250068991  116541952   83  Linux
```

Then I installed Ubuntu Natty and specified the partitions manually so that `/dev/sda1` became the `/boot` partition formatted with ext2, `/dev/sda2` the swap and `/dev/sda3` the `/` formatted with ext4. After the installation the thing didn't boot, and I ended up in the grub-rescue console which doesn't make any sense to me. It's giving me:

```
error: invalid arch independent ELF magic.
grub rescue>
```

Have I done some mistakes during my installation? How do I solve the issue with grub-recovery?

Comment: can you seperate the answer from your question?

Comment: I will, I'm currently reinstalling the OS to verify the solution.

Comment: Sigh... the installer should **just do this** automatically or at least make it a preseed switch. http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=609293

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Boot into Live CD and run:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda3 /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```

Comment: For EFI machines, you'll need to install grub-efi while booted in the live-CD, otherwise you'll get some puzzling errors.

Comment: Just want to point out that `--boot-directory` (`b` instead of `r`) as written elsewhere does *not* work. Just got kicked into a different looking grub shell.

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed the same problem with Backtrack , on VMware. The boot was broken after installing vmware tools

I used the following commands to fix it:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```