# Several GRUB error messages on startup

Tags: 11.04, grub2

Fresh Natty installation gives me some GRUB error messages on startup:

```
error: file not found.
error: file not found.
error: no suitable mode found.
error: no video mode activated.
error: file not found.
error: file not found.
```

Regardless of these errors it boots up. It probably is somewhat related to [my previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37692/grub-file-not-found-after-natty-install-on-ssd) as I specified the partitions manually and ended up in the GRUB recovery console. To solve that I booted from Live CD and ran:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda3 /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```

Do those errors matter? How to get rid of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All that was required to fix it was running`sudo update-grub` in terminal.