# GRUB - ELF magic error message after installation - how to get dual boot option?

Tags: 11.10, installation, grub2

I attempted to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7. (Intel i5 2300 H67 chipset)

Unfortunately, after a seemingly successful installation I got the message:

GRUB: “invalid arch independent ELF magic”
grub rescue>

Another answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72003/grub-invalid-arch-independent-elf-magic-after-11-10-install-on-macbook-pro-5/72995#72995) suggests I should enter these commands below, which should be customised for my own partitions.

```
sudo apt-get install grub-efi-amd64
sudo mount /dev/sda3 /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot 
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```

My partitions are...

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848   819202047   409497600    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       819202048  1228802047   204800000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4      1228804094  1953523711   362359809    5  Extended
/dev/sda5      1228804096  1936926719   354061312   83  Linux
/dev/sda6      1936928768  1953523711     8297472   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

However, I'm a bit unsure how I can adapt those commands above because I want to be able to dual-boot with windows 7. (if those commands are appropriate for me anyway).

Given my partitions above, how can I get GRUB to give me a dual boot option?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to fix this by using the live cd and entering the commands:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```

I can successfully access both Ubuntu and Windows.