# remove grub and reinstall linux

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, grub-efi

I installed Lubuntu and I realize I messed something up,so I boot into windows and delete the partition and remove grub.
Later when I fix the problem and reinstall Lubuntu,the installer gives a message said that `grub-efi-amd64-signed` cannot be installed.
Does it mean that I did not remove grub completely?If so,how do I remove it completely?

Comment: is hibernate and fast startup disabled in windows?

Comment: @ravery yes it is disabled

Comment: By the sounds of it, you've removed your ESP (EFI System Partition). Are you able to post your partition layout? You can use any partitioning software you want to do this. Take a screenshot and post it in your question.

Comment: @marko I did not remove the ESP,the only thing I did to it is remove grub

Comment: @marko -- windows would not allow that

Comment: @sosad9556 -- one possible solution is here https://askubuntu.com/a/938472/694267

Comment: Ok I stand corrected. To complement ravery's answer, this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing) - section "via the LiveCD terminal" may be of benefit the the OP in relation to reinstalling GRUB via the command line.

Comment: @marko I tried the method above but it failed to install grub

Comment: Sorry to hear that, if possible, please take a screenshot / photo and post it in your question so we can see what else is displayed on your screen.