# Ubuntu already there how to access it

Tags: partitioning

Im trying to install ubuntu alongside Windows 10 on an Dell insprion 15 or 17. Im using a USB to install it. I used rufus to burn the iso
Im using UEFI bios and this is probably the 20th time at least  trying to install ubuntu and none of those times have been successful. Im using try ubuntu right now.   I see there is a install Ubuntu option 
and I see an erase ubuntu 16 lts and reinstall option.
Ive already tried that option numerous time none of which was successful, everytime I get an error saying grub-install/dev/sdb failed or something like that. So therefore I go the something else option and go onto select my partition. I see that there is already an Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS on a partition called SDB7 as EXT4
I was wondering how can I access that partition and boot onto that partition
which already has ubuntu installed on it.
Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Dell often has RAID turned on, it needs to be changed to AHCI it that is your issue. But add the AHCI drivers first into Windows or Windows will stop working. Also make sure Windows fast start up is off. Are you installing in UEFI mode or BIOS mode? If UEFI to sdb, it will still install to the ESP - efi system partition on sda (even though saying installing to sdb). And if installing in UEFI mode to sdb partition in advance and include an ESP, even if not currently used. Best as first partition.

Comment: UEFI, how do I check for fast start up?

Comment: Ive turned off fast start up

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this with many computers, it is not the grub install that actually fails but the update-grub that makes the first config file that fails. the problem is that the if/then statement in 30_uefi-firmware errors.

the easiest fix is after it error, choose the command line prompt at the bottom of the installer menu. and use nano to edit the file /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware. I have changed mine to read:

```
gettext_printf "Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration\n" >&2
cat << EOF
menuentry 'uefi-firmware' {
fwsetup
}
EOF
```

after editing rerun install grub. note: on some systems the print command needs to be commented out temporarily for the installer

If you want to try and boot the installed Linux to make repairs from there.

there is a guide for booting an install from the grub command line here https://askubuntu.com/a/931327/694267

you will have to change the drive references as needed for your installation

Comment: @GuyNaeem DO NOT post your email here.  If you need comments moved to a chat room you can request that with a custom mod flag on a comment in the chain.  I've created the chatroom for you and ravery to continue your discussion in.  (FYI that posting your email here reveals personally identifiable information that can be used to spam you)  Moving the support discussion to email also does not help for others who may wish to help you as well.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66783/discussion-on-answer-by-ravery-ubuntu-already-there-how-to-access-it).

Comment: how do I access the chatroom?  Sorry about that

Comment: @GuyNaeem there's a link in my previous comment - where it says "moved to chat".  Click it and you'll be joined in.  You might have to relogon to the StackExchange system if it prompts, but you and ravery can continue your discussion in there.