# GRUB terminal instead of menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, bootloader, boot-repair

I've Windows dual booted with Ubuntu. So recently, I moved one of my free partition so that it would be near the Ubuntu partition and I could expand the Ubuntu partition. But when I moved the free space partition and rebooted the system, I'm stuck at the GRUB terminal instead of the menu.

When I use F12 to get the boot options and choose Ubuntu from there, it redirects me back to GRUB terminal. Windows, however boots normally.

Here is the GRUB terminal output I tried diagnosting

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sg0GO.jpg)

I listed the drives using ls command and I think that `(hd0,1)` is the Linux partition. Can anyone guide me as to what should be my next step? I'm new to Linux environment and clueless as to how things work around here.

Comment: hd0,1 is a Linux cd not an install. Try first loading the fs driver `insmod ext2` then run ls on the partitions again.

Comment: Moving partitions can move where they are found by grub.  You need should run [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) from a LiveCD.  That link should have the instructions on how to do it.

Comment: Yes, hd0 isa n installation usb-drive. And (hd1,2) is your ESP (EFI System Partition) and there should be grubx64.efi file. Show us the content of (hd1,2)/boot and (hd1,2)/efi.

Comment: @Terrance I tried Boot Repair, but it didn't work. Here is the link to the log file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zCjUgHN19ovDyTd6PZakac2J__UPCDsv/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: @Evgeniy Yanuk you're right, (hd1,2) is the one. Here's the link to contents:  https://imgur.com/gallery/3K97g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to mount file systems grub needs to load modules. These modules are address by physical sector. Moving the root partition, moved these files; thus grub can no longer find them. You need to reinstall grub.

#### The simplest method:

Boot a LiveCD. and run `boot repair`. Double check what it wants to do.Some people have had difficulty with boot repair on an EFI system. Be sure the LiveCD boots in EFI mode.

#### Manually Boot from grub command prompt:

again be sure to boot EFI mode. In grub menu from the LiveCD, press <kbd>C</kbd> to get a command line prompt. then enter the following commands:

```
linux (hd1,3)/vmlinuz root=/dev/sda3
initrd (hd1,3)/initrd.img
boot
```

If your root partition isn't (hd1,3), then change all the drive references as needed. More detailed instructions can be found here: https://askubuntu.com/a/931327/694267

Comment: I'm unable to find vmlinuz or initrd files. Can you look at my screenshots and tell something.

Comment: @archity -- can you post the partition info in gparted from the LiveCD?

Comment: Partition info: https://imgur.com/gallery/rNfRC

Comment: you don't have any linux partitions. you have to reinstall.

Comment: I had installed Linux in the 50GB earlier. Will reinstalling in that partition solve the problem of GRUB too?

Comment: yes reinstalling will also reinstall grub.

Comment: Reinstalling in the same partition solved the problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @archity Please accept this answer so your question stops popping up on the main board as unanswered. Thank you.