# GRUB: terminal instead of Grub menu list

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, bootloader

I'm running into the problem, that my boot entries are not showing up in the grub bootloader and I have no clue why.

I looked at similar questions like this one and tried their solution, which didn't work: [GRUB terminal instead of menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/989238/grub-terminal-instead-of-menu)

I'm running grub2-efi on a gpt formatted m2 ssd. Neither boot repair, reinstalling or setting the root/linux/initrd things through grub worked for me.

At this point I really don't know where to look further.

I can still boot my separate OS by selecting them in the UEFI boot menu (I have Windows 10 and PopOS installed), but I would like to use grub instead which is a lot esier. In the grub terminal which appears on boot, it will boot my linux install when I type `exit`, which is strange to me.

Also strange to me, is that I have only Windows 10 and PopOS installed, but for PopOS I see multiple bootable instances with different names: `UEFI OS (will boot grub terminal), PopOS (will boot PopOS directly) and pop (will boot grub terminal)`

The closest I have come to a solution is was to follow these steps provided in the answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329926/grub-starts-in-command-line-after-reboot

After running all the commands in grub, I was able to see the grub menu. Then I booted into linux and immediately ran `grub-update`. Unfortunately, after rebooting the menu was gone again. I tried this several times. It seems like the grub config is not being persisted or something similar.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Although PopOS may be based upon Ubuntu, this site only deals with Ubuntu issues.

Comment: Thank you guys for the feedback. You're right, this probably does not fit askUbutnu, as it seems this is the cause of PopOS itself. Anyways, I switched to rEFInd which was very easy to set-up and works like a charm now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue but i resolve it with this tutorial: https://jacci.net/linux/pop-os/how-to-install-grub-on-pop-os-20-04/

Comment: Thank you, this might help others. I've done some research on PopOS's site and seen a few forum posts where PopOS admins advice to use rEFInd instead of grub.
Idk, maybe PopOS tinkered with Grub so these tweaks are necessary, but installing rEFInd was definitely the easier option with PopOS (it's even in their default apt repositories list)