# Unable to boot after applying recovery in dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I dual booted Ubuntu 16.04 with Windows 10. After applying the recovery using `tar` in Ubuntu, I restarted the system, and GRUB shows this error:

```
error : no such device : [then a long number]
error : no such partition
error : you need to load the kernel first.
```

What should I do ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I boot my PC from GRUB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/929833/how-do-i-boot-my-pc-from-grub) The restored grub config file references non existent partitions UUIDs. The linked quest will tell you how to boot from grub command line so you can reinstall/update grub

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? Pre-installed Windows 10 is UEFI, and upgrades from Window 7 is usually BIOS. What brand/model system? May be best to see details, you can run from your Ubuntu live installer or any working install, use ppa version not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/