# Grub2 opens when loading Ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, 17.10

I had an image of my linux machine which is Ubuntu 17.10 and now restored it. But when I boot my machine and choose Ubuntu I get the below screen of grub2. I wonder how I can load my Ubuntu system?

[image]

Comment: If a restored Ubuntu, you may have mismatch with grub in MBR and grub in your install. Probably easiest to just reinstall grub. May be best to see details, you can run from your Ubuntu live installer or any working install, use ppa version not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I boot my PC from GRUB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/929833/how-do-i-boot-my-pc-from-grub)