# Install GRUB on a separate virtual partition to boot a physical Ubuntu installation in VM

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, virtualization, vmware

I have a dual-boot Ubuntu 17.10/Windows 10 machine. They all reside on a 512GB NVMe SSD and GRUB is installed as main bootloader (GPT partition table).

From Windows 10, I now want to boot the Ubuntu install, so I created a "virtual" NVMe disk in VMWare Workstation that uses the physical Ubuntu EXT4 partition + the swap partition.

The problem is that the system does not boot as there is no bootloader.

So I created a proper virtual disk in VMWare where I was planning to install another GRUB instance (from a Live CD) to start the Ubuntu installation. The problem is that GRUB wants me to chroot to the existing install, while all I want is just to install another GRUB on the virtual disk.

Here is the VM configuration, the ticked boxes are the partitions used in VMWare Workstation.

[image]

Is this the correct way to proceed? What do I have to do to continue?

EDIT:
Not a duplicate. I am not asking how to install GRUB. GRUB is already installed on the pysical DISK. But since I am using only some partitions of that very disk I need to install a copy of GRUB in ANOTHER VIRTUAL partition that has no OS, so definitely can't EITHER access to the already existing GRUB, NOR install it as I'd usually do from a Live CD.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I boot my PC from GRUB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/929833/how-do-i-boot-my-pc-from-grub)

Comment: Have you at least read my question or the word "GRUB" in the title classifies it as a duplicate?

Comment: have you read the link? boot the VM with the install disk to get the grub command prompt, boot the installed linux from grub command line and install grub. no chroot needed. the linked dup is the exact procedure that will allow you to install grub in the VM.

Comment: Sorry if I sounded a bit harsh, it wasn't meant. Anyway yes: I read the link and do not understand how could it be linked to my question. I do not get to the GRUB prompt. There's no GRUB at all. There's the Live CD start screen or nothing (if I disconnect the CD).

Comment: the LiveCD start screen should be grub, type "C" to get a command prompt. you can use anything that gives you grub to do this.

Comment: tried with Xubuntu and Kubuntu Live CDs, "C" does not bring to me to anything. Only thing I can do is to change the kernel args.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73307/discussion-between-ravery-and-francis-straccia).