# New Install Boots to Grub

Tags: boot, grub2

UPDATE:

I followed these instructions to make this work: [How do I boot my PC from GRUB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/929833/how-do-i-boot-my-pc-from-grub)

I had to boot from my USB installer thumb drive to pull up the Disk information so I knew what device to point the root to.

I also ran a software update.

How do I configure this so that I don't have to type these commands every single time and it will just load Ubuntu automatically?

---

There have been many posts about this, but unfortunately, none of the answers to them have solved my problem.

I am installing Ubuntu for the very first time. I've never used Linux before. I followed all of the instructions about creating swap and EXT partitions on my hard drive (250GB SSD).

I reformatted an old SSD that used to have a windows installation on it to be used exclusively for Ubuntu.

Installing from UEFI off a USB stick.

No matter what I do, the computer always boots to Grub and won't load the Linux kernel.

When I run ls to search the other hard drives to find the linux installation, sometimes it says ./efi ./Trashes. Most of the time it says "Unknown File System." And in one case it returns nothing.

Can anyone help me boot linux from grub? I'm at a loss.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the default install method where the installer does all the partitioning? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1152400/edit) your question and add new information. Is this a dual boot with Windows? Are you installing in UEFI or Legacy mode?

Comment: Creating a swap partition has been unnecessary for year for most users, so your instructions may be perhaps obsolete, of poor quality, or maybe you made mistakes or took shortcuts following them. Since we don't know which instructions you followed, or what you actually did, we can't help you much beyond "Try installing again"...perhaps with [better instructions](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0).

Comment: Updated post. Thanks.

Comment: Try booting with Live USB and using boot repair: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104855/how-to-make-grub-menu-appear-instead-grub-minimal-bash-like-in-booting

Answer (score 0):

I sort of fixed my issue yesterday. Here is the post. But it's not perfect. I still have two instances of ubuntu on the UEFI boot drive selector screen, and selecting them boots to Grub. But, I can select the hard drive Ubuntu is installed on and it boots directly to the OS.

[How do you boot automatically from Grub?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1152428/how-do-you-boot-automatically-from-grub?noredirect=1#comment1916264_1152428)