# I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 today. Now, after restarting it goes to GNU GRUB 2.02 and then I cannot go further. Please help

Tags: 18.04, grub2, upgrade, 20.04

So I am not knowledgeable about computers.
Upgraded today to 20.04 when prompted.  Screen goes to and stops at GNU GRUB version 2.02,
with underneath;

Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions.  Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or fil completions.

grub>

What do I do from here?

Comment: Hello!  I had this problem yesterday, I fix it with typing exit,  have you tried that?  (I know it sounds like a trivial thing,  but try it, and reply if it worked)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I boot my PC from GRUB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/929833/how-do-i-boot-my-pc-from-grub)

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't use manual partitioning, so your boot is in UEFI mode.
Type `reboot` after `grub>`, press `Enter`, after restart press `F12` (or something else, depends on your laptop or PC) go to your boot menu, set your boot option `UEFI`.

Ubuntu 20.04 use boot on `UEFI` mode not `LEGACY`. (if you use minimal installation from `mini.iso` image, you can boot it on `LEGACY` mode)