# Problem with boot - initramfs: Waiting for /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv to appear

Tags: boot, partitioning, kernel, mount, lvm

initramfs: Timeout while waiting for devices for / (and possibly /usr) filesystems to appear (did you specified correct ones)
initramfs: Will cause kernel panic in 10s...

I chrooted to /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv and can see files. Tried mount directories to update initramfs but it shows 0 kernels..

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem, to solve this I would better go into grub, it has more functionality than initramfs.  You can try booting up from Grub ([How do I boot my PC from GRUB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/929833/how-do-i-boot-my-pc-from-grub)) or from USB stick with Ubuntu on it. After booting up, you have to reconfigure grub config files. Try sudo update-grub or vi /boot/grub/grub.cfg and almost at the end of the file you should be able to adjust from "Linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root ro quiet splash $vt_handoff" to your hard drive with root partition. In my case it was: "Linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/mapper/nvme0n1p3_crypt ro quiet splash $vt_handoff"