# Dual boot EFI error: "invalid arch independent ELF magic"

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

After installing Ubuntu 11.10 on a pc which already has Windows 7 I get this error:

```
error: invalid arch independent ELF magic.
grub rescue>
```

So I used Supergrub boot disk to get into Ubuntu. And made sure that `grub-efi-amd64` package is present, and I ran `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` command. That also led to the same error. Then I tried the solution given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37692/grub-invalid-arch-independent-elf-magic-after-natty-install-on-ssd) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72003/grub-invalid-arch-independent-elf-magic-after-11-10-install-on-macbook-pro-5). That also gave same error. `fdisk -ul /dev/sda` shows that boot partition (/dev/sda1) is a msdos partition. `/dev/sda6` is root partition and `/dev/sda9` is the home partition. So, how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Please update: mark an answer accepted if it worked or edit the question to say you gave up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been almost four months, but if you still need a solution, my recommendation is to switch to a different boot loader. In my experience, GRUB 2 (which Ubuntu uses by default) is the *least* reliable of the common EFI boot loaders for Linux. Given that you're dual-booting with Windows, you're probably best off with either [Fedora's patched GRUB Legacy](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/grub_legacy.html) or a combination of [ELILO](http://elilo.sourceforge.net/) and either [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) or [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net). Of these, you can do the combination of ELILO and rEFIt using Ubuntu packages, but you'll need to do some manual configuration, and Ubuntu's rEFIt package has some bugs on UEFI-based PCs. (It works better on Macs.) Thus, you'll probably have to go beyond the packaging system to manually download either GRUB Legacy or rEFInd.

Comment: Wow, finally got my new PC to work again after installing rEFInd. New Core i7, didn't even boot to windows, just using a new separate SSD with 12.04 fresh install. OEM HDD not even plugged in. This is an epic fail on Ubuntu's part. :( They should pay you for UEFI support.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem “invalid arch independent ELF magic”.

I was installing from a USB stick booted from the Bios in UEFI mode.

After a couple a couple unsuccessful reinstallation of 12.04,I tried the same installation with the the USB stick booted without the UEFI mode and it works.

For your information my setting on a 120GB SSD
sda1 /windows 90 GB   windows 7 64bits
sda2 /boot  100 MB
sda5 swap     1 GB
sda6 /        18GB   ubuntu 12.04
sda7 /home     8GB

My motherboard is P8P67 Pro with Asus EZbios and I had two choices in my boot menu for the USB with 12.04 installation.

Hope it helps!