# Fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 amd64 does not boot

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, boot-failure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GRUB: “invalid arch independent ELF magic” after install on SSD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37692/grub-invalid-arch-independent-elf-magic-after-install-on-ssd)

Can not boot fresh installation of 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04. Got next message right after reboot:

```
error: invalid arch independent ELF magic.
grub rescue>
```

What is wrong? How can I fix it without reinstall?

Comment: @Sergey - Possibly this will help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/37692/grub-invalid-arch-independent-elf-magic-after-natty-install-on-ssd

Comment: Re install if nothing to lose else try to update grub via live cd

Answer (score 0):

Boot into Live CD and run:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda3 /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```