# error: invalid arch independent ELF magic. dual boot with SSD

Tags: 12.04, grub2, dual-boot, ssd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GRUB: “invalid arch independent ELF magic” after install on SSD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37692/grub-invalid-arch-independent-elf-magic-after-install-on-ssd)

I am currently trying at get a dual boot computer to work, where the Ubuntu 12.04 operating system is spread over two drives.

The setup of the two drives are:

HDD:
<sub>/dev/sda1 /boot/efi

/dev/sda2 some unknown msftres at 128MB (don't bother about this as long as the rest works)

/dev/sda3 Windows 7

/dev/sda4 /home

/dev/sda5 swap

/dev/sda6 /tmp

/dev/sda7 /var</sub>

SSD:
<sub>/dev/sdb1 /</sub>

In an attempt to combine speed with SSD durability. That might be a topic in itself, but for now I would be very happy just to get the grub bootloader to work.

When booting at either HDD or SSD, I get this error:

```
error: invalid arch independent ELF magic.
grub rescue>
```

Comment: Unlike the above, where / and /boot were on separate partitions, yours is all on /dev/sdb1, is that correct? Are you booting from the hard disk or from the SSD?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem “invalid arch independent ELF magic”.

I was installing from a USB stick booted from the Bios in UEFI mode.

After a couple a couple unsuccessful reinstallation of 12.04,I tried the same installation with the the USB stick booted without the UEFI mode and it works.

For your information my setting on a 120GB SSD

sda1 /windows 90 GB windows 7 64bits

sda2 /boot 100 MB

sda5 swap 1 GB

sda6 / 18GB ubuntu 12.04

sda7 /home 8GB

My motherboard is P8P67 Pro with Asus EZbios and I had two choices in my boot menu for the USB with 12.04 installation.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Fixed the elf arch magic problem for me. The installer then failed with migration assistant but that's separate.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the same problem with Backtrack on VMware the boot was broken after installing vmware tools.

I used the following commands :

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

then

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```