# GRUB: “invalid arch independent ELF magic” - usr/sbin/grub-bios-setup: Not found

Tags: installation, boot, grub2

I just got over with installing Ubuntu 13.04 on my Asus laptop from a USB stick. After the installation finished and the computer restarted, it started up with a *GRUB: invalid arch independent ELF magic* error. I looked around on Google to find out a solution and found Cadoc's thread [How do I resolve a GRUB: “invalid arch independent ELF magic” error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72003/grub-invalid-arch-independent-elf-magic-after-11-10-install-on-macbook-pro-5) and followed the solution up to the line

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```

When I typed that command, I got

```
/usr/sbin/grub-bios-setup: Not found.
```

and I couldn't find any solution for that after some searching on Google. So what do I have to do to fix that and get thing going fine?

Answer (score 1):

If `grub-bios-setup' is not found, you probably have a [EFI mode](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Identifying_if_an_Ubuntu_has_been_installed_in_EFI_mode) installation of Ubuntu.

```
[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo "Installed in EFI mode" || echo "Installed in Legacy mode"
```

If this is not the case, something went really bad during installation. You can try using [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to fix your problem.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

Comment: It turned out that my installation wasn't in EFL mode, so I'm going to try second solution. There's only one thing, where should I enter the two lines you provided? I mean in which directory do I have to be, considering that I am booting from a USB stick.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bad grub install. If you can boot using the USB Drive into a Live ISO mode (the "try Ubuntu" option), you should be able to re-install grub and get the system up and running. Check to see if your BIOS uses UEFI as well.

See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37692/grub-invalid-arch-independent-elf-magic-after-install-on-ssd).

Have a nice day.